# error "objects are not valid as a react child" in react native

Tags: react-native

"objects are not valid as a react child (found: object with keys {date, events}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of View."

So I have kind of a cascade of method calls. I'm retrieving dates with events inside of those. It feels like I'm doing this correctly, but am getting the above error. I've tried setting createFragment on places, but still getting the error. Here's the code:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import {
    AppRegistry,
    Text,
    View,
    ScrollView,
    RefreshControl,
    StyleSheet,
    Dimensions,
    TextInput,
    Linking,
    TouchableNativeFeedback
   } from 'react-native';

  var _ = require('lodash');
  var {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
  var renderif = require('render-if');
  var createFragment = require('react-addons-create-fragment');

  var IMAGES_PER_ROW = 1

  class FunInATL extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        currentScreenWidth: width,
        currentScreenHeight: height,
        dates: [],
        boxIndex: 0,
        showBox: false,
        refreshing: false
      };
    }

        handleRotation(event) {
          if (!this.state) {
            return;
          }

          var layout = event.nativeEvent.layout
          this.state({currentScreenWidth: layout.width, currentScreenHeight: layout.height })
        }

        calculatedSize() {
          var size = this.state.currentScreenWidth / IMAGES_PER_ROW
          return {width: size}
        }

        renderRow(events) {
          return events.map((events, i) => {
            return (
              <Image key={i} style={[this.getImageStyles(), styles.image, this.calculatedSize() ]} source={{uri: event.image}} />
            )
          })
        }

        openUrl(url) {
          Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
              if (supported) {
                Linking.openURL(url);
              } else {
                console.log('nope :: ' + url);
              }
          }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
        }

        getImageStyles(featured, category) {
            let options = {
              borderColor: 'gold',
              borderWidth: featured ? 1 : 0
            }

            if (!category) {
                options.height = featured ? 250 : 125
            }

            return options;
        }

        _clickImage(event, index) {
          if (event.title) {
            let new_val = !this.state.showBox
            this.setState({
                dates: this.state.dates,
                showBox: new_val,
                boxIndex: new_val ? index : 0
            });
          }

        }

        componentDidMount() {
          this.state = {
              dates: [],
              boxIndex: 0,
              showBox: false,
              refreshing: false
          };
          this.getApiData();

          Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleUrl);
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleUrl);
        }

        getApiData() {
          var _this = this;
          return fetch('https://www.funinatl.com/mobile2.php?v1')
            .then(function(response) {
              return response.json()
            })
            .then((responseJson) => {
              var dates = createFragment(responseJson.events)
              return;

              let _this = this;

              date.events.map((event, i) => (
                date.events[i] = event
              ))

              var datesData = [];
              dates.map((date, i) => (
                datesData.push({
                  date: i,
                  events: createFragment(date.events)
                })
              ))

              _this.setState({
                dates: createFragment(datesData),
                boxIndex: 0,
                showBox: false
              })

              console.error(this.state);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
            })
            .done();
        }

        renderDates() {
          return this.state.dates.map((date) =>
                (
                  <View>
                    <Text style={styles.dateHeader}>{ date.date }</Text>

                    <View>
                    {this.renderEvents(date.events)}
                    </View>
                  </View>

            ))
        }

        renderImage(event, index) {
            if (this.state.showBox && this.state.boxIndex == index) {
              return (
                <View>
                  <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={()=>this._clickImage(event, index)}>
                      <Image source={{ uri: event.image }} style={[styles.image, this.calculatedSize(), this.getImageStyles(event.featured), { height: 100 }]} />
                  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                  <View style={{ flexDirection:'row', padding: 15 }}>
                      <Text style={styles.price}>{event.price}</Text>
                      <Text style={styles.time}>{event.time}</Text>
                      <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={()=>this.openUrl(event.website)}>
                          <Text style={styles.btn}>Website</Text>
                      </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                  </View>

                      {renderif(event.venue)(
                          <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={()=>this.openUrl(event.venue)}>
                              <Text style={styles.btn}>Venue</Text>
                          </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                      )}

                </View>
              )
            } else {
              return (
                <View>
                    <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={()=>this._clickImage(event, index)}>
                        <Image source={{ uri: event.image }} style={[styles.image, this.calculatedSize(), this.getImageStyles(event.featured)]} />
                    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                </View>
              )
            }
        }

        renderEvents(events) {
          return events.map((event, i) =>
            (
              <View>
                <Text style={[styles.eventCategory, this.getImageStyles(event.featured, true)]}>{event.category}</Text>
                <View>
                  {this.renderImage(event, i)}
                </View>
                <Text style={[styles.eventTitle, this.getImageStyles(event.featured, true)]}>{event.title}</Text>
              </View>
          ));
        }

        _onRefresh() {
          this.setState({refreshing: true});
          fetchData().then(() => {
            this.setState({refreshing: false});
          });
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <ScrollView onLayout={this.handleRotation} contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView} refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl
                  refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                  onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
                  tintColor="#ff0000"
                  title="Loading..."
                  titleColor="#00ff00"
                  colors={['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff']}
                  progressBackgroundColor="#ffff00"
                />
              }>
              <Text style={styles.header}>FunInATL</Text>
                  {this.renderDates()}
            </ScrollView>
          )
        }
      }

  var styles = StyleSheet.create({

    row: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
      textAlign: 'center',
      padding: 10
    },

    header: {
      fontSize: 30,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      padding: 20,
      textAlign: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#000',
      color: '#fff'
    },

    dateHeader: {
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      padding: 20,
      textAlign: 'left',
      color: '#fff',
      backgroundColor: '#283593'
    },

    eventCategory: {
        backgroundColor: '#03a9f4',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#ffffff',
        padding: 3
    },

    eventTitle: {
        borderTopWidth: 0,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        padding: 3,
        fontSize: 18,
    },

    image: {
    },

    btn: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        padding: 10,
        color: '#fff',
        textAlign: 'center',
        flex: 1
    },

    price: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        fontSize: 16,
        flex: 1
    },

    time: {
      marginRight: 10,
      fontSize: 16,
      flex: 1,
      width: 35
    }

  });

  AppRegistry.registerComponent('FunInATL', () => FunInATL);
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Updated code per the map suggestion, still not working. complaining about {events} only now.

**EDIT 2**: Updated with FULL code.

Answer (score 1):

The component's render helpers, such as `renderDates()`, are returning `_.each(...)`. `_.each()` returns its first argument so this is why you are receiving the error.

To illustrate:

```
const myObject = { a: 1 };
_.each(myObject) === myObject // true
```

I recommend you use `Array.prototype.map()` instead:

```
return this.state.dates.map((date) => (
  <View>...</View>        
));
```

If you use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like I did in the example above, there's no need to save a reference to `this`. `this` in the body of the function passed to `map()` will be bound to the instance of the component. You can then call other helper methods such as `getImageStyles()` like `this.getImageStyles(...)`.

This is not related to your original question but the `getApiData()` method will not work. You can replace the function in the chain that handles `responseJson` with something like:

```
(responseJson) => {
  this.setState({
    dates: Object.entries(responseJson.events).map(([date, { events }]) => ({
      date,
      events,
    })),
    boxIndex: 0,
    showBox: false,
  });
}
```

You also need to to remove the `this.state = {...}` in `componentDidMount()`. Notice the [warning in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) that indicates you should "NEVER mutate this.state directly".

Comment: Edited above with new code, same problem. Now it just does it for {events} instead.

Comment: Are you sure you're posting the full code? `getApiData()` returns `undefined`. I'm also not sure what `createFragement()` is but it's not necessary here. Finally, you should remove `this.state = {...}` in `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: Not the full code, thought it would be enough...but i've posted the contents of my index.ios.js file

Comment: I am also getting the same error for https://github.com/kushmpatel/auth_React_Demo this demo. Can you please checkout this project and check it? I am learning react native and seriously have no idea where is the problem in my code?